How to install things?
Some apps have .appimage and source code tar archive as download options. I migrated from Windows 11 and to me it seems that app image is like portable executable on Windows, correct me if I'm wrong. So how do I actually install a program so that I can launch it from start menu(or however it's called in Linux)?

You'll use apt or apt-get via a terminal, or Synaptic Package Manager to install via GUI.   apt-get Howto or Synaptic Howto

Does this answer your question? What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it? Please read all answers to that question.

I also migrated from Windows once upon a time.. I think I understand your misunderstanding. :)
You are used to installing software by downloading executable files. This is how it mostly works in Windows. In Ubuntu the case is different... for the most part.
Software is downloaded using apt or apt-get in the terminal (which is a kind of command line app store), or by using the GUI app Ubuntu Software (as it is called in 22.04) or App Center (as it is called in 24.04).
Here is a link to a page where the apt command is described in more detail.
https://itsfoss.com/apt-command-guide/
